# Low orbit space debris affects magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields, estimation, geomagnetism

[image]Theory reduce earth temperature by removing low orbit junk and consolidating needed satellites 
With all the space junk in low orbit, we effect both earth's magnetic field by moving metals into the magnetic  field that are generated to protect from gamma Ray’s the I creasing metal also reflects gamma  rays bouncing off the earths surface it’s like wrapping the earth with Reynolds wrap and placing us in a space oven 
We need so much more research into the planet and how to save it from ourselves. 
This maybe crazy I am no scientist and have little experience with magnetic but if you apply Tesla's theory the metal in space make sense it will effect the natural defense our planet has.

Comment: Have you tried to do a back-of-an-envelope estimation?

Comment: The figure on the right grossly over exaggerates the amount of space debris in orbit. Consider the effect on Earth's magnetic field of a swam of gnats on a summer evening...

Answer (score 1):

No, space junk does not affect the earth's magnetic field.

I think your confusion stems from the image with the space junk, in which the junk seems to form a thick shell. In reality, the satellites and pieces of junk are extremely tiny compared to the earth, and they are separated by great distances. If a 10 cm piece of junk gets within 100 km of a satellite, people are worried as that is too close for comfort.

In addition, most of the space junk is made of non-magnetic materials like aluminium, stainless steel and titanium. Of course, as they travel through the earth's magnetic field, that will induce currents in them, but those currents are so small as to be completely negligible.

I'm not sure I understand your comments about gamma rays. They do not "bounce off the earth's surface"; instead, they penetrate the earth. They also penetrate the material of the spacecraft so, if anything, you could say that the junk reduces the gamma ray flux ever so slightly. Gamma rays are also not affected by magnetic fields, which affect only charged particles. As for Tesla, he had some good ideas (like AC power) as well as crazy ones that have been discredited. I don't know which of his theories you are talking about.

Comment: Gamma rays are absorbed by the atmosphere.